# Using facebook likes to access fb app

Tags: php, facebook

I have created an fb app using a page tab on my fb page.  However before a user can access the app I would like the user to like my page first.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook banned this practice in 2014.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a Page. This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content based on whether or not a person has liked a Page. It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app's Page. To ensure quality connections and help businesses reach the people who matter to them, we want people to like Pages because they want to connect and hear from the business, not because of artificial incentives. We believe this update will benefit people and advertisers alike.

As a result, Facebook removed any technological ability to do this from the API:

> The liked field will no longer be returned in the page property of the signed_request object for Page Tab apps created from today onwards. For apps created before today, from November 5, 2014 (90 days from today), the liked property will always return true regardless of whether or not the person has liked the page.

If you want people to like your page, **make it worth liking.**

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Is there a best or preferred way to give people access to the App?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You could have them register, you could use Facebook's login API to let them in that way, or you could leave it open to all visitors. Depends on you and your app.